# WinPython 64bit crashes when importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I see an error when I try to run my 'import pandas as pd' line in my WinPython 3.4 64bit.

This error is not present when I do the same in WinPython 3.4 32bit

The error when importing into WinPython 3.4 64bit looks like this:

> ```
> > In [2]:
> > runfile('Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject/structuring_tweets.py',
> > wdir='Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject') DLL load failed: %1 is
> > not a valid Win32 application. Traceback (most recent call last):
> > 
> >   File "<ipython-input-2-f4d4b6486e47>", line 1, in <module>
> >     runfile('Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject/structuring_tweets.py',
> > wdir='Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject')
> > 
> >   File "C:\Program Files
> > (x86)\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
> > line 682, in runfile
> >     execfile(filename, namespace)
> > 
> >   File "C:\Program Files
> > (x86)\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.2\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py",
> > line 85, in execfile
> >     exec(compile(open(filename, 'rb').read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
> > 
> >   File "Z:/python/CrystallBall/SpyderProject/structuring_tweets.py",
> > line 10, in <module>
> >     import pandas as pd
> > 
> >   File
> > "C:\Users\Morten\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python34\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py",
> > line 7, in <module>
> >     from . import hashtable, tslib, lib
> > 
> > ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
> ```

Can anyone help me with solving this? There must have been others that have tried to run pandas in Winpython 3.4 (64) and have seen this error.

Comment: Is this only happening in spyder? I use ipython in winpython 64-bit and never seen this, you could try reinstalling again, the installer allows you to install to any directory

Comment: Same thing in iPython console... Then I might be a problem on my end. My installation (which I made yesturday) must be off somehow. Yikes!  :o(
Heeelp

Comment: I'd just try installing it again to a different directory

Comment: Reinstalled it with the same outcome. I guess I'm stuck at 32 bit for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weird - but it seems that the problem with Spyder crashing in WinPython 3.4 (64bit) is not present in WinPython 3.3.5.7 (64bit). So now I am running SPyder IDE from this installation.

I think someone should have a serious look at my described problem above.

Thanks guys